# first child element of particular type

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some section with three children (one `<h1>` and two `<div>`)

```
<section class="half">
  <h1>Half</h1>
  <div>
    left half
  </div>
  <div>
    right half
  </div>
</section>
```

Then I am adding some styles to these blocks

```
section > h1 { ... }
section > div { ... }
```

I want to specify additional styles for the first `<div>` element in the section.

I can't write use just `section > :first-child` because first child in section is `<h1>`.

So how I should write?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-of-type) is for:

```css
section > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    /* CSS properties go here... */
}
```

Comment: Be careful with the 'nth' selectors, IE was late to the party. nth-of-type won't work in less than IE9 (!). Is there a reason you can't just add classes to them, class="left" and class="right" is more semantic.

Comment: @David Gilbertson: Class names carry zero semantics. And I dare say that class names like `left` and `right` are even worse than not having class names at all.

Comment: @BoltClock, What I mean is that class names can meaning to the css (perhaps semantics is the wrong word). If I was reading a selector ".left-column-wrapper" (or whatever) in CSS, I've got a good idea of what the rule is doing. If the selector is "section > div:nth-of-type(1)", I'd be hunting through the DOM to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-of-type)

Answer (score 1):

Using only `section > div:nth-of-type(1) {` will select first `div` element where parent element is `section`, and hence I feel will be a loose selector, make it stricter by using

```
section.half > div:nth-of-type(1) { /* This will select 1st div element inside
                                     * section having class .half
                                     */
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyqBS/1/)

You can also use `first-of-type` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyqBS/)

```
section.half > div:first-of-type {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aYprN/)**

No doubt, [**Joseph Silber** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879683/1823761) is great. But if you don't want to use CSS3, here is the trick:

```
section > div { background: red; }
section > div + div { background: transparent; }
```

First, you select **all** div elements and set your properties to it. Then, you select second div and later and
reset those properties for it.

Comment: How is `div + div` not CSS3?

Comment: @JosephSilber I think that `+` selector is CSS2, [see this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector).

Comment: Thant you for this approach, but I have no reasons for not using CSS3. :)

Comment: This will break for any `div` that doesn't immediately follow a `div`. You can't really do this without using a CSS3 selector.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, **exactly** right, I just offer this trick in this case. I also correct my `jsFiddle` writing as you said it before `;)`.